# Error del compilador al instalar una libreria

Tags: c++

He instalado la librería criterion en codeblocks ,pero me tira una serie de errores de compilación y no se a que se debe.

```
main.cpp|6|undefined reference to _imp__criterion_internal_test_setup'|

main.cpp|6|undefined reference to `_imp__criterion_internal_test_main'|
```

Comment: El código fuente en C debe contener los `#include` apropiados donde se definan las funciones de la librería que va a usar. Además, al no ser una librería estándar, cuando compiles cualquier programa que la use debes especificarlo en las opciones del compilador. No sé cómo se hará en CodeBlocks, pero desde línea de comandos normalmente consiste en añadir la opción `-l` seguida (sin espacios) del nombre de la librería. Por ejemplo `-lpthread` para usar la librería `libpthread`.

Comment: esta puesto #include y la libreria linkeada, criterion es una librería de testeo no se si eso puede afectar ya que he visto que con gtest tambien da errores de compilación, voy aprobar linkeando -lcriterion haber si funciona.

Comment: Sí, va a ser lo del linker. Si miras la animación que sale [en su documentacion](https://github.com/Snaipe/Criterion) verás que ponen esa opción al compilar

Comment: He intentado linkear la libreria pero me tira los siguientes errores en el log : ld.exe||cannot find -lcriterion|

Comment: Tu pregunta tal y como está redactada ahora mismo no es de ayuda para que podamos averiguar tu problema. ¿Podrías añadir el código que estás usando?